# Is there a way to specify the NuGet package ID when running 'kpm build'?

Tags: asp.net-core, kpm

When running `kpm build` against a project folder, the project.json metadata for the following fields is transferred to the output .nupkg file:

- Version
- Authors
- Description

However, there does not seem to be a way to override the package ID or title (which defaults to the name of the containing folder).

Is this possible or is it necessary to produce a nuspec file through some other means in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible to specify a different name.

What's the scenario in which you need a different name?

Comment: Purely that I have a project.json file in the root of a git repo and like lowercase repo names but want a Pascal case project name. However it makes sense that this is convention-based so I can just nest the project a directory deeper.

Comment: Take a look at how the ASP.NET team is doing it. The projects are inside the `src` or `test` folders https://github.com/aspnet/XRE

Comment: `src` would be my usual convention but as the repo is so small it doesn't make much sense to have a dedicated `src` folder - I can however just create a subdirectory for the specific project name and put the project.json in there :)